# Customize colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2D array that I'm plotting with `imshow` and I would like to have costums colors depending on the value of each pixel of my array. I'll explain it with an example.

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *

img = ones((5,5))
img[1][1] = 2

imshow(img,interpolation='nearest');colorbar()
```

If you ran this code you would see a red square in a blue background. The red square corresponds to the pixel `[1][1]` in `img`, while the other pixel are colored blue because they have a value of 1. What if I want the red square to be colored with a custom color?
Or more generally, if I have a 2D array like `img` in the example, how can I color pixel with the same value with a color I can choose.

I have found this page that explains how to generate a custom colorbar but that's not useful: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link you sent has the following:

> But, what if I think those colormaps are ugly? Well, just make your
>   own using matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap. First, create a
>   script that will map the range (0,1) to values in the RGB spectrum. In
>   this dictionary, you will have a series of tuples for each color
>   'red', 'green', and 'blue'. The first elements in each of these color
>   series needs to be ordered from 0 to 1, with arbitrary spacing
>   inbetween. Now, consider (0.5, 1.0, 0.7) in the 'red' series below.
>   This tuple says that at 0.5 in the range from (0,1) , interpolate from
>   below to 1.0, and above from 0.7. Often, the second two values in each
>   tuple will be the same, but using diferent values is helpful for
>   putting breaks in your colormap. This is easier understand than might
>   sound, as demonstrated by this simple script:

```
   1 from pylab import *
   2 cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
   3                  (0.5, 1.0, 0.7),
   4                  (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
   5          'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
   6                    (0.5, 1.0, 0.0),
   7                    (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
   8          'blue': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
   9                   (0.5, 1.0, 0.0),
  10                   (1.0, 0.5, 1.0))}
  11 my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap',cdict,256)
  12 pcolor(rand(10,10),cmap=my_cmap)
  13 colorbar()
```

Isn't this exactly what you want?

Here's an example of how to do it with the image you provided:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

img = ones((5,5))
img[1][1] = 2

cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                (0.5, 1.0, 0.7),
                     (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
             'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                       (0.5, 1.0, 0.0),
                       (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
             'blue': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      (0.5, 1.0, 0.0),
                     (1.0, 0.5, 1.0))}

my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap',cdict,256)
plt.pcolor(img,cmap=my_cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Also, if you really want to map a number to a colour you can use discrete_cmap as specified in that example you linked to, here's the example method the scipy documentation provides:

```
def discrete_cmap(N=8):
    """create a colormap with N (N<15) discrete colors and register it"""
    # define individual colors as hex values
    cpool = [ '#bd2309', '#bbb12d', '#1480fa', '#14fa2f', '#000000',
              '#faf214', '#2edfea', '#ea2ec4', '#ea2e40', '#cdcdcd',
              '#577a4d', '#2e46c0', '#f59422', '#219774', '#8086d9' ]
    cmap3 = col.ListedColormap(cpool[0:N], 'indexed')
    cm.register_cmap(cmap=cmap3)
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use this information to do what I need.

Comment: Sorry - I've added an example, is this is more helpful? Tell me if not and I'll go into some more detail.